# Нюансы организации прикладного уровня сетевого взаимодействия

Tags: c++, tcp

Пишу велосипед с архитектурой клиент сервер. Возник вопрос, как реализовать алгоритм, который будет распознавать конец пакета. Я сделал обмен через хмл документы и алгоритм распознавания конца пакета сделал в виде алгоритма Бойера Мура Хорспула. В душе я понимаю что это конкретный костыль. Как лучше реализовать этот алгоритм?

Comment: Ничего распознавать не надо, надо указать длину пересылаемых данных в начале.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарии вроде как ответ есть, добавлю, конец сообщения можно проверять по наличию в конце например "\r\n\r\n" как в http, но при этом, что-то может потеряться и вы об этом не узнаете. А вообще вы что имеете в виду под словом "пакет", tcp пакет или то что вы в send поместили? А так, лучше в начале сообщения вставлять его длину, и в цикле после каждого recv проверять всё ли пришло. Тем не менее целостность сообщения это не гарантирует, для этого можно хэш сообщения передавать например в конце.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Правда теперь возник вопрос про целостность. Раньше думал что одна из задач тсп проверка целостности. Это так но оказалось что алгоритм там слабый (прочитал в Вики). В связи с этим предлагается делать проверку на целостность самим (хотя почему тупо в тсп не сделали тот же sha256 или любую другую функцию, непонятно). Так вот, если я каким то чудом сделаю проверку целостности и она найдёт нарушение, то как мне сказать чтобы пакет переслали заново??? Я тут вижу несколько проблем: 1. Пока я буду проверять, придет ещё куча пакетов. 2. Как сказать тсп чтобы он переслал битый пакет?

Comment: Примерно представил. Такие проблемы можно решить на прикладном уровне)

Comment: Можно наверное по-разному, я вот сейчас делаю общение между двумя сервисами, сделал 2 канала, один для запросов, другой для ответов, и по обоим каналам приходит статус в ответ.   
Например в первый посылаем `get: xxx.jpg`, в этом же канале получаем статус сразу например `status:ok`, и делаем дальше запросы, вот если получили плохой статус, значит просто заново отправляем сообщение. А во втором канале ждём уже сам ответ(картинку в данном случае), и так же отвечаем туда статусом, на плохой статус собственно, перепосылка должна быть. Это асинхронная система, сообщения нужно помечать каким-то id.

Comment: Можно просто вот как в HTTP 1.1, один запрос делаем, и в этом же соединении ответ ждём ничего больше не посылая пока не получим ответ.

Comment: Вы, получается, сами нарезаете посылку на размер полезной нагрузки тсп (если на каждый запрос в том же канале ждёте ответ)?  И почему два канала сделали (как я понял два тсп соединения на одного клиента)? Это же не совсем рационально будет. Мне казалось что достаточно одного порта

Comment: Ничего не нарезаю, send в цикле запускаю , пока все данные не отправит, хоть 2ГБ кидай туда. С двумя каналами как-то удобней получается, не надо мультиплексировать всё подряд, например клиент посылает много мелких запросов по 100байт, и в то же время сервер шлёт ответ на 100МБ, и пока он его шлёт, мы не можем узнать статус наших запросов, надо тогда резать на части всё самостоятельно, чтобы в любой момент можно было приостанавливать посылку большого ответа, чтобы послать более приоритетные мелкие статусы, да и если что-то пошло не так, разрываем и переподключаем один канал, не трогая другой.

Comment: Да и там надо размеры считать каждого куска, id  вставлять и так далее, мне кажется, больше ресурсов на это уйдёт. А 2 канала же держим постоянно, не закрывая их, так что они не требуют ресурсов, самое требовательное это установка соединения. Я на самом деле не до конца определился со всем этим, но пока всё работает довольно удобно. Вам наверное надо HTTP2 смотреть.

Comment: Забыл сказать, что схема с 2 каналами больше подходит, когда мы не ожидаем получить ответ сразу. Какой-нибудь эхо-сервер конечно надо в один канал.